# Attribute error:module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'

Tags: python, attributeerror, python-3.6

I downloaded a speech recognition from pypy.

It was 3.6.0 version and extracted it in Lib folder inside python folder.
Its name was something speechrecognition 3.6 and I changed it to speech_recognition and then it was not showing an error like "no such module", but inside that, there was another folder with the same name so I changed it also and now even though it has Recognizer folder it says:

> AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'

Please help, I am new to python.

Code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio 
# Record Audio
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# Speech recognition using Google Speech Recognition
try:
    # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
    # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, 
key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
    print("Speech was:" + r.recognize_google(audio, language = "en-us", 
show_all=False))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio") 
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; 
{0}".format(e))
```

Comment: What else do you expect when changing random names of your libraries?

Comment: I don't think the intended setup process involves manually renaming two folders. Have you tried following the [official installation instructions](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#installing)?

Comment: i chnaged the names because it was showing error that no module named speech recognition.please tell what should i do after extracting it in Lib folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and found the solution with the help of the StackOverflow community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178391/speech-recognition-attributeerror-module-speech-recognition-has-no-attribute?s=3%7C210.0341).

The error was that my file name was also speech_recognition and python was checking the file instead of the library. Changing my file name solved the problem.