# Speech Recognition: AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'

Tags: python, speech-recognition, spyder, attributeerror

I'm trying to run a speech recognition using the [Speech Recognition Project](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)

I installed SpeechRecognition as illustrated. My code ran correctly for a few times.

I was trying to input different files. Now I started getting the following error:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-a4d5c9aae5d0>", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition as sr

  File "/Users/Sashank/Documents/Deep_Learning_A_Z/Personal Projects/Speech recognition/speech_recognition.py", line 7, in <module>
    r = sr.Recognizer()

AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'
```

The confusing thing is that I'm only executing the first line of the code, which is to import the library. And it returns the error.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

And the error seems to be corresponding to the next line of code, which I've not yet executed:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
```

I'm new to both programming as well as to python. I'm using spyder3. I've restarted the kernel a few times. I tried to install SpeechRecognition again on terminal. I closed and opened spyder also a few times, but now facing the same error again and again.

Please help.

Full Code:

```
# Speech Recognition

# Importing Library
import speech_recognition as sr

# Creating a recognition object
r = sr.Recognizer()

# Extracting the audio & removing ambient noice
audio_file = sr.AudioFile('ambient_noise_recording.wav')
with audio_file as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.record(source)

# Recognize the audio
r.recognize_google(audio)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> File "/Users/Sashank/Documents/Deep_Learning_A_Z/Personal Projects/Speech recognition/**speech_recognition.py**", line 7, in

Your name of the file is `speech_recognition.py` and python is looking not to the `speech_recognition` module but search the `Recognizer` in your module (file).

You need simple to rename your module (file).

For example from `speech_recognition.py` to `sp_recog.py`

Comment: never thought this could be a problem here, thanks mann!