# How can I use audio file as audio source in SpeechRecognition in Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, speech-recognition, avaudiofile, audio-source

I used `speech_recognition.AudioFile` in Python 3.6 , but this error was indicated:

```
AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'AudioFile'
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain path to "english.wav" in the same folder as this script
from os import path
AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "english.wav")
# AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "french.aiff")
# AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "chinese.flac")

# use the audio file as the audio source
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file
```

In addition I am using `speech_recognition 3.1.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change to a newer version of SpeechRecognition? Your code works smoothly using the latest version, but version 3.1.3 doesn't seem to have that feature yet and triggers the error for me aswell.

Alternatively is the filename of your script called speech_recognition.py? Someone had that problem:
[Speech Recognition: AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51178391/12479101)

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try typing fewer commands

Paste the .wav file in the current working directory

then remove AUDIO_FILE

and type:

with sr.AudioFile("english.wav") as source

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain path to "english.wav" in the same folder as this script
#from os import path
#AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "english.wav")
# AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "french.aiff")
# AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "chinese.flac")

#  use the audio file as the audio source
# paste the .wav file int current working directory
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile("english.wav") as source:
     audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file
```

Comment: Hi, you should provide an explaination of your code along with the snippet to improve your answer